# Pokemon go loading login help

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I know this question has been asked and answered before but I have tried everything those questions had to offer on those threads so please don't delete this post saying it's a duplicate because those threads did NOT help.

So my pokemon go whenever I try to log in is constantly just sitting there with a spinning pokeball. I have a picture as well:

[image]

It has been loading for 45 minutes and still nothing. What else can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix!

Go to your Google app and go to the accounts, unsync both of them and completely log out of both of them on your phone and then log back into the google account that didn't work, then the app seemed to work for me!